# Replace a letter in a table name if matched a pattern?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Here is my code

```
    SELECT
       obj.name objName,
       col.xtype colxtype
    FROM
       ${dbName}.dbo.sysobjects obj
    LEFT JOIN
       ${dbName}.dbo.syscolumns col
    ON
       obj.id = col.id
    LEFT JOIN
       ${dbName}.sys.default_constrains def
    ON
       def.object_id = col.cdefault
    WHERE
       obj.xtype = 'U'
       AND obj.name =
       (
           SELECT
              tableDBName
           FROM
              XXXXXX_TableID
           WHERE
              TableID = #{tableid}
       )
    ORDER BY
       col.colorder
```

I'd like to make it if {tableid} starts with 'WTN' then remove the letter T from it and then do the sql with the new tableid without the T.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired restuls.

Comment: Example: WTN0001
Desired result: WN0001

Comment: I suggest you really THINK about your code. First, you should not generally use three-part names. Your connection should determine the database to be use for all object references. Here we don't know the current database of the connection and if that differs from the value of ${dbName}. You don't use a three-part (or two-part) name for "XXXXXX_TableID" and it is troubling that you have a table name that includes "TableID" (which sounds like a column) that also contains a column named TableID which is compared to the tableid parameter. IMO this is not a good sign.